# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'linear' of undefined

Tags: d3.js

I'm new to D3 and getting the following  error in my demo script -

**FirstD3.jsp:31 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'linear' of undefined**

My demo code is as follow

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>Linear Scales</title>
<style type="text/css">

</style>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var dataset = [
           [ 5,     20 ],
           [ 460,   90 ],
           [ 250,   50 ],
           [ 100,   33 ],
           [ 330,   95 ],
           [ 410,   12 ],
           [ 468,   44 ],
           [ 25,    67 ],
           [ 85,    21 ],
           [ 220,   88 ]
       ];
var w = 500;
var h = 100;


var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(d) { return d[0]; })])
        .range([0, w]);

var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(d) { return d[1]; })])
        .range([0, h]);

var svg = d3.select("body")
      .append("svg")
      .attr("height", h)
      .attr("width", w);

      svg.selectAll("circle")
         .data(dataset)
         .enter()
         .append("circle")
         .attr("cx", function (d) {
             return xScale(d[0]);
         })
         .attr("cy", function(d) {
             return yScale(d[1]);
         })
         .attr("r", function (d) {
             return Math.sqrt(h-(d[1]));
         });

      svg.selectAll("text")
         .data(dataset)
         .enter()
         .append("text")
         .text(function (d) {
             return d[0]+","+d[1];
         })
         .attr("x", function (d) {
             return xScale(d[0]);
         })
         .attr("y", function (d) {
             return yScale(d[1]);
         })
         .attr("font-size", "11px")
         .attr("fill", "red");



</script>
</body>
</html>
```

what is causing this error? and how to solve it

Comment: In d3 4.x it's `d3.scaleLinear()`.

Answer (score 223, accepted):

In D3 **v4** it is no longer named `d3.scale.linear()`. Use `d3.scaleLinear()` instead.

Comment: I'm new to D3.js, d3.scale.ordinal() is undefined in d3 v4? relevant method  for ordinal scaling

Comment: @Megajin detailed info about changes https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md#scales-d3-scale

Comment: If you get an error using `d3js.org/d3.v4.js` then try `d3js.org/d3.v3.js`

Comment: Note the capital 'L' in scaleLinear()

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the answer, I've solved this error for the following code (I'm studing D3.js) :

`var colorScale = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 100]).range(["#add8e6", "blue"]);`

With the following error (inside the web page) :

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'linear' of undefined at index.html:22`