# TypeError: Cannot read property 'linear' of undefined in Angular using NvD3Module

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, d3.js, nvd3.js

I'm currently trying to display a candlestick chart in my Angular 7 application. I'm using the [nvd3 module](https://github.com/krispo/ng2-nvd3).

In the app.module.ts file, I imported the module and its dependencies :

```
import { NvD3Module } from 'ng2-nvd3';
import 'd3';
import 'nvd3';
```

And in my `stock-details.component.ts`, I created the chart like this :

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.symbol = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('symbol');

    this.options = {
      chart: {
        type: 'candlestickBarChart',
        height: 450,
        margin : {
          top: 20,
          right: 20,
          bottom: 40,
          left: 60
        },
        x: function(d) { return d['date']; },
        y: function(d) { return d['close']; },
        duration: 100,

        xAxis: {
          axisLabel: 'Dates',
          tickFormat: function(d) {
            return d3.time.format('%x')(new Date(new Date() - (20000 * 86400000) + (d * 86400000)));
          },
          showMaxMin: false
        },

        yAxis: {
          axisLabel: 'Stock Price',
          tickFormat: function(d) {
            return '$' + d3.format(',.1f')(d);
          },
          showMaxMin: false
        },
        zoom: {
          enabled: true,
          scaleExtent: [1, 10],
          useFixedDomain: false,
          useNiceScale: false,
          horizontalOff: false,
          verticalOff: true,
          unzoomEventType: 'dblclick.zoom'
        }
      }
    };

    this.data = [{values: [
        {'date': 15854, 'open': 165.42, 'high': 165.8, 'low': 164.34, 'close': 165.22, 'volume': 160363400, 'adjusted': 164.35},
        {'date': 15855, 'open': 165.35, 'high': 166.59, 'low': 165.22, 'close': 165.83, 'volume': 107793800, 'adjusted': 164.96},
        {'date': 15856, 'open': 165.37, 'high': 166.31, 'low': 163.13, 'close': 163.45, 'volume': 176850100, 'adjusted': 162.59},
        {'date': 15859, 'open': 163.83, 'high': 164.46, 'low': 162.66, 'close': 164.35, 'volume': 168390700, 'adjusted': 163.48},
        {'date': 15860, 'open': 164.44, 'high': 165.1, 'low': 162.73, 'close': 163.56, 'volume': 157631500, 'adjusted': 162.7},
        {'date': 15861, 'open': 163.09, 'high': 163.42, 'low': 161.13, 'close': 161.27, 'volume': 211737800, 'adjusted': 160.42},
        {'date': 15862, 'open': 161.2, 'high': 162.74, 'low': 160.25, 'close': 162.73, 'volume': 200225500, 'adjusted': 161.87},
        {'date': 15863, 'open': 163.85, 'high': 164.95, 'low': 163.14, 'close': 164.8, 'volume': 188337800, 'adjusted': 163.93},
        {'date': 15866, 'open': 165.31, 'high': 165.4, 'low': 164.37, 'close': 164.8, 'volume': 105667100, 'adjusted': 163.93},
        {'date': 15867, 'open': 163.3, 'high': 164.54, 'low': 162.74, 'close': 163.1, 'volume': 159505400, 'adjusted': 162.24},
        {'date': 15868, 'open': 164.22, 'high': 164.39, 'low': 161.6, 'close': 161.75, 'volume': 177361500, 'adjusted': 160.9},
        {'date': 15869, 'open': 161.66, 'high': 164.5, 'low': 161.3, 'close': 164.21, 'volume': 163587800, 'adjusted': 163.35},
        {'date': 15870, 'open': 164.03, 'high': 164.67, 'low': 162.91, 'close': 163.18, 'volume': 141197500, 'adjusted': 162.32},
        {'date': 15873, 'open': 164.29, 'high': 165.22, 'low': 163.22, 'close': 164.44, 'volume': 136295600, 'adjusted': 163.57},
        {'date': 15874, 'open': 164.53, 'high': 165.99, 'low': 164.52, 'close': 165.74, 'volume': 114695600, 'adjusted': 164.87},
        {'date': 15875, 'open': 165.6, 'high': 165.89, 'low': 163.38, 'close': 163.45, 'volume': 206149500, 'adjusted': 162.59},
        {'date': 15876, 'open': 161.86, 'high': 163.47, 'low': 158.98, 'close': 159.4, 'volume': 321255900, 'adjusted': 158.56},
        {'date': 15877, 'open': 159.64, 'high': 159.76, 'low': 157.47, 'close': 159.07, 'volume': 271956800, 'adjusted': 159.07},
        {'date': 15880, 'open': 157.41, 'high': 158.43, 'low': 155.73, 'close': 157.06, 'volume': 222329000, 'adjusted': 157.06},
        {'date': 15881, 'open': 158.48, 'high': 160.1, 'low': 157.42, 'close': 158.57, 'volume': 162262200, 'adjusted': 158.57},
        {'date': 15882, 'open': 159.87, 'high': 160.5, 'low': 159.25, 'close': 160.14, 'volume': 134848000, 'adjusted': 160.14},
        {'date': 15883, 'open': 161.1, 'high': 161.82, 'low': 160.95, 'close': 161.08, 'volume': 129483700, 'adjusted': 161.08},
        {'date': 15884, 'open': 160.63, 'high': 161.4, 'low': 159.86, 'close': 160.42, 'volume': 160402900, 'adjusted': 160.42},
        {'date': 15887, 'open': 161.26, 'high': 162.48, 'low': 161.08, 'close': 161.36, 'volume': 131954800, 'adjusted': 161.36},
        {'date': 15888, 'open': 161.12, 'high': 162.3, 'low': 160.5, 'close': 161.21, 'volume': 154863700, 'adjusted': 161.21},
        {'date': 15889, 'open': 160.48, 'high': 161.77, 'low': 160.22, 'close': 161.28, 'volume': 75216400, 'adjusted': 161.28},
        {'date': 15891, 'open': 162.47, 'high': 163.08, 'low': 161.3, 'close': 163.02, 'volume': 122416900, 'adjusted': 163.02},
        {'date': 15894, 'open': 163.86, 'high': 164.39, 'low': 163.08, 'close': 163.95, 'volume': 108092500, 'adjusted': 163.95},
        {'date': 15895, 'open': 164.98, 'high': 165.33, 'low': 164.27, 'close': 165.13, 'volume': 119298000, 'adjusted': 165.13},
        {'date': 15896, 'open': 164.97, 'high': 165.75, 'low': 164.63, 'close': 165.19, 'volume': 121410100, 'adjusted': 165.19},
        {'date': 15897, 'open': 167.11, 'high': 167.61, 'low': 165.18, 'close': 167.44, 'volume': 135592200, 'adjusted': 167.44},
        {'date': 15898, 'open': 167.39, 'high': 167.93, 'low': 167.13, 'close': 167.51, 'volume': 104212700, 'adjusted': 167.51},
        {'date': 15901, 'open': 167.97, 'high': 168.39, 'low': 167.68, 'close': 168.15, 'volume': 69450600, 'adjusted': 168.15},
        {'date': 15902, 'open': 168.26, 'high': 168.36, 'low': 167.07, 'close': 167.52, 'volume': 88702100, 'adjusted': 167.52},
        {'date': 15903, 'open': 168.16, 'high': 168.48, 'low': 167.73, 'close': 167.95, 'volume': 92873900, 'adjusted': 167.95},
        {'date': 15904, 'open': 168.31, 'high': 169.27, 'low': 168.2, 'close': 168.87, 'volume': 103620100, 'adjusted': 168.87},
        {'date': 15905, 'open': 168.52, 'high': 169.23, 'low': 168.31, 'close': 169.17, 'volume': 103831700, 'adjusted': 169.17},
        {'date': 15908, 'open': 169.41, 'high': 169.74, 'low': 169.01, 'close': 169.5, 'volume': 79428600, 'adjusted': 169.5},
        {'date': 15909, 'open': 169.8, 'high': 169.83, 'low': 169.05, 'close': 169.14, 'volume': 80829700, 'adjusted': 169.14},
        {'date': 15910, 'open': 169.79, 'high': 169.86, 'low': 168.18, 'close': 168.52, 'volume': 112914000, 'adjusted': 168.52},
        {'date': 15911, 'open': 168.22, 'high': 169.08, 'low': 167.94, 'close': 168.93, 'volume': 111088600, 'adjusted': 168.93},
        {'date': 15912, 'open': 168.22, 'high': 169.16, 'low': 167.52, 'close': 169.11, 'volume': 107814600, 'adjusted': 169.11},
        {'date': 15915, 'open': 168.68, 'high': 169.06, 'low': 168.11, 'close': 168.59, 'volume': 79695000, 'adjusted': 168.59},
        {'date': 15916, 'open': 169.1, 'high': 169.28, 'low': 168.19, 'close': 168.59, 'volume': 85209600, 'adjusted': 168.59},
        {'date': 15917, 'open': 168.94, 'high': 169.85, 'low': 168.49, 'close': 168.71, 'volume': 142388700, 'adjusted': 168.71},
        {'date': 15918, 'open': 169.99, 'high': 170.81, 'low': 169.9, 'close': 170.66, 'volume': 110438400, 'adjusted': 170.66},
        {'date': 15919, 'open': 170.28, 'high': 170.97, 'low': 170.05, 'close': 170.95, 'volume': 91116700, 'adjusted': 170.95},
        {'date': 15922, 'open': 170.57, 'high': 170.96, 'low': 170.35, 'close': 170.7, 'volume': 54072700, 'adjusted': 170.7},
        {'date': 15923, 'open': 170.37, 'high': 170.74, 'low': 169.35, 'close': 169.73, 'volume': 87495000, 'adjusted': 169.73},
        {'date': 15924, 'open': 169.19, 'high': 169.43, 'low': 168.55, 'close': 169.18, 'volume': 84854700, 'adjusted': 169.18},
        {'date': 15925, 'open': 169.98, 'high': 170.18, 'low': 168.93, 'close': 169.8, 'volume': 102181300, 'adjusted': 169.8},
        {'date': 15926, 'open': 169.58, 'high': 170.1, 'low': 168.72, 'close': 169.31, 'volume': 91757700, 'adjusted': 169.31},
        {'date': 15929, 'open': 168.46, 'high': 169.31, 'low': 168.38, 'close': 169.11, 'volume': 68593300, 'adjusted': 169.11},
        {'date': 15930, 'open': 169.41, 'high': 169.9, 'low': 168.41, 'close': 169.61, 'volume': 80806000, 'adjusted': 169.61},
        {'date': 15931, 'open': 169.53, 'high': 169.8, 'low': 168.7, 'close': 168.74, 'volume': 79829200, 'adjusted': 168.74},
        {'date': 15932, 'open': 167.41, 'high': 167.43, 'low': 166.09, 'close': 166.38, 'volume': 152931800, 'adjusted': 166.38},
        {'date': 15933, 'open': 166.06, 'high': 166.63, 'low': 165.5, 'close': 165.83, 'volume': 130868200, 'adjusted': 165.83},
        {'date': 15936, 'open': 165.64, 'high': 166.21, 'low': 164.76, 'close': 164.77, 'volume': 96437600, 'adjusted': 164.77},
        {'date': 15937, 'open': 165.04, 'high': 166.2, 'low': 164.86, 'close': 165.58, 'volume': 89294400, 'adjusted': 165.58},
        {'date': 15938, 'open': 165.12, 'high': 166.03, 'low': 164.19, 'close': 164.56, 'volume': 159530500, 'adjusted': 164.56},
        {'date': 15939, 'open': 164.9, 'high': 166.3, 'low': 164.89, 'close': 166.06, 'volume': 101471400, 'adjusted': 166.06},
        {'date': 15940, 'open': 166.55, 'high': 166.83, 'low': 165.77, 'close': 166.62, 'volume': 90888900, 'adjusted': 166.62},
        {'date': 15943, 'open': 166.79, 'high': 167.3, 'low': 165.89, 'close': 166, 'volume': 89702100, 'adjusted': 166},
        {'date': 15944, 'open': 164.36, 'high': 166, 'low': 163.21, 'close': 163.33, 'volume': 158619400, 'adjusted': 163.33},
        {'date': 15945, 'open': 163.26, 'high': 164.49, 'low': 163.05, 'close': 163.91, 'volume': 108113000, 'adjusted': 163.91},
        {'date': 15946, 'open': 163.55, 'high': 165.04, 'low': 163.4, 'close': 164.17, 'volume': 119200500, 'adjusted': 164.17},
        {'date': 15947, 'open': 164.51, 'high': 164.53, 'low': 163.17, 'close': 163.65, 'volume': 134560800, 'adjusted': 163.65},
        {'date': 15951, 'open': 165.23, 'high': 165.58, 'low': 163.7, 'close': 164.39, 'volume': 142322300, 'adjusted': 164.39},
        {'date': 15952, 'open': 164.43, 'high': 166.03, 'low': 164.13, 'close': 165.75, 'volume': 97304000, 'adjusted': 165.75},
        {'date': 15953, 'open': 165.85, 'high': 166.4, 'low': 165.73, 'close': 165.96, 'volume': 62930500, 'adjusted': 165.96}
      ]}];
  }
```

(sorry for the long code, but it's mostly data values anyway...). As you could have guessed, I just copy-pasted the official [Github example](https://github.com/krispo/angular-nvd3/blob/gh-pages/js/candlestickBarChart.js) at this point.

For some reason, it doesn't work. The only things that are succesfully displayed on the page are the static HTML parts. I have this strange error in my console :

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'linear' of undefined
    at Object.push../node_modules/nvd3/build/nv.d3.js.nv.models.candlestickBar (nv.d3.js:3110)
    at Object.push../node_modules/nvd3/build/nv.d3.js.nv.models.candlestickBarChart (nv.d3.js:6131)
    at NvD3Component.push../node_modules/ng2-nvd3/build/lib/ng2-nvd3.component.js.NvD3Component.initChart (ng2-nvd3.component.js:26)
    at NvD3Component.push../node_modules/ng2-nvd3/build/lib/ng2-nvd3.component.js.NvD3Component.ngOnChanges (ng2-nvd3.component.js:11)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:18616)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:19884)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:19846)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:20480)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:20440)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (StockDetailsComponent.html:6)
```

My HTML code looks like this : `<nvd3 [options]="options" [data]="data"></nvd3>`. Again, straight from the example in the doc...

I did some research and I've found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38450349/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-linear-of-undefined) of Stackoverflow. Being really desperate I went to node_modules/nvd3/build/nv.d3.js and replaced all the occurences of `d3.scale.linear()` by `d3.scaleLinear()`. Of course, it didn't work and this time I had a different error ("cannot read property category20 of undefined") so I undid the changes. It's the first time I'm using D3 and really can't find where the problem comes from.

Edit : Here's the full HTML file as requested :

```
<app-nav></app-nav>

<section>
  <h2>Stock information for : {{ symbol | uppercase }}</h2>

  <nvd3 [options]="options" [data]="data"></nvd3>

</section>
```

Comment: The error is originating from your HTML file it seems. Can you please add the HTML template as well?

Comment: I just added the code. It's really basic HTML.

Comment: Are you able to reproduce the problem in a StackBlitz?

Comment: I'm using ng2-nvd3 version 2.0.0 and nvd3 version 1.8.6?

Comment: I'm gonna try give me a few seconds

Comment: I can't seem to find a way to import it but here's a link to Github if it can help : https://github.com/tofl/Flitterman-Exchange

Comment: The Github page for ng2-nvd3 says you need v3.5.17 of d3. You've got 5.7.0

Comment: Ah thank you very much. It removed the error but now I have another one which, hopefully, will be easier to solve : `src/app/stock-details/stock-details.component.ts(39,50): error TS2362: The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number' or an enum type.`

Comment: Here's the line 39 : `return d3.time.format('%x')(new Date(new Date() - (20000 * 86400000) + (d * 86400000)));`

Comment: `new Date()` is an object, so you can't do `new Date() - 20000`, because it's not a number. You need to do `new Date().getTime() - 20000`

Comment: It worked ! Thank you so much ! You just solved my problem in just a few minutes even though you couldn't see the full code haha. Thank you kind stranger. I guess I'm not very experienced yet :)